# Mongodb C# GeoNEar is slow

Tags: c#, mongodb

I've added a GeoNear Function with Mongodb C# like that:

```
` var options = GeoNearOptions.SetMaxDistance(rangeInKm / earthRadius /* to radians */)
                                                    .SetSpherical(true).SetDistanceMultiplier(6378.137);
                    collection.EnsureIndex(IndexKeys.GeoSpatial("PlacePoint"));'


 MongoDB.Driver.GeoNearResult<MongoPlace> Georesults = collection.GeoNear(Query.Null, coordinates[0], coordinates[1], TakeNum,options);
```

I have over 3000 places in the data... it's taking too long.
how can I make it better

Comment: You really need to provide more details on "too long"; what are you actually measuring, what are your server specs?  I would also suggest reviewing [`mongostat`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongostat/) output collected while your query is executing on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be useful to know just how long "too long" is, as that could be highly relative.  It could also help to know what version you're running, as well as what sort of hardware you're running on.

But given just the information that you have above, one potential slowdown is your

```
collection.EnsureIndex(IndexKeys.GeoSpatial("PlacePoint"));
```

It looks like you might be running that before every query, which would be a no-no, since you should only create an index on your collection once, and I would guess that that could be slowing you down.

You might try running your command from the mongo shell, like so (substituting your real values for my placeholders, of course):

```
db.runCommand( { geoNear: "<collectionName>", near: [<lon>,<lat>], num: <num>, spherical:true } )
```

Then look at the "stats" information to see if there's something there that seems amiss.  I personally have a collection with 234107 places with a geospatial index on them, and I ran a geoNear command with coordinates that were intentionally far away from any of the places in my collection to help ensure that it would scan every one of them.  I got the following results (running version 2.2.3 on modestly powerful hardware: Core i5, 16 GB RAM, 7200 RPM HDD - data set consisted of fairly small documents consisting of the lat/lon points + a small amount of additional data):

```
    "stats" : {
            "time" : 261,
            "btreelocs" : 0,
            "nscanned" : 234107,
            "objectsLoaded" : 133,
            "avgDistance" : 1.380670166668938,
            "maxDistance" : 1.3807179692447809
    },
```

On a query that was closer to places in my collection, I got:

```
    "stats" : {
            "time" : 15,
            "btreelocs" : 0,
            "nscanned" : 6211,
            "objectsLoaded" : 29,
            "avgDistance" : 0.003811909711576418,
            "maxDistance" : 0.003919781450489085
    },
```

The "time" here is in milliseconds, which seems very reasonable to me.  Running the GeoNear function in C# has always returned near instantly for me, so I don't think that your slow results would be due to any inefficiency of the C# driver, either.

Comment: The [ensureIndex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/#db.collection.ensureIndex) command is effectively a no-op if called multiple times with the same spec and should not be a significant slowdown (although it's definitely unnecessary to call repeatedly).